# Save Stored Procedure output variable in Batch Script Variable

Tags: sql, batch-file, stored-procedures

**Aim: Run a stored procedure from a Batch Script and save its output variable to a variable in the Batch Script.**

I'm 90% there but I'm stuck with this issue. I have a stored procedure that runs against our database and depending on the current values in the database returns a 1-character VARCHAR2 - either Y or N.

The sql that calls the stored procedure (I've renamed the parameters and calls for the sake of security):

```
set serveroutput on
variable out_val varchar2;
exec SCHEMA.STOREDPROCEDURE('INPUT1', 'INPUT2', :out_val);
print out_val
exit
```

The sql file is called from a Batch Script designed to check whether out_val is set to Y or N. My current batch call looks like this:

```
@echo on
set strYN = ' '

rem This line needs to store the value Y or N in a variable to be echoed at the end of the script.
for /F "usebackq" %%i in (`sqlplus schema/PW@USER @"sqlcall.sql"`) do set stryn=%%i

echo %strYN%
pause
```

I get the following output. My Batch variable is being set to the first word of the last line of the SQL connection:

```
>set strYN = ' '
>rem ** This line needs to store the value Y or N in a variable to be echoed at the end of the script.
>for /F "usebackq" %i in (`sqlplus schema/PW@USER @"sqlcall.sql"`) do set stryn=%i
>set stryn=SQL*Plus:
>set stryn=Copyright
>set stryn=Connected
>set stryn=Oracle
>set stryn=With
>set stryn=PL/SQL
>set stryn=STOREDPROCEDURE
>set stryn=OUT_VAL
>set stryn=--------------------------------
>set stryn=N
>set stryn=Disconnected
>set stryn=With
>echo With
With
>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Instead, I'd like it to be set to N. One thought was to put an IF statement within my usebackq's DO section to check whether the variable was set to Y or N. However, I feel like there's a way to do this that simply plucks the value of out_val into my strYN Batch variable. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you alawys have the same number of lines as output :

```
for /F "skip=9 delims=" %%i in ('sqlplus schema/PW@USER @"sqlcall.sql"') do (
   set stryn=%%i
   goto:next)

:next
echo Stryn=%stryn%
```

If not make an `IF` test on `!stryn!` :

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "skip=9 delims=" %%i in ('sqlplus schema/PW@USER @"sqlcall.sql"') do (
   set stryn=%%i
   if /i "!stryn!"=="N" (goto:nextN) else (if /i "!stryn!"=="Y" goto:nextY)
)
exit /b

:nextN
echo Stryn=!Stryn!
exit /b

:nextY
echo Stryn=!Stryn!
```

Comment: I agree. This option would work in theory but I'm not 100% sure that the command will produce the same number of lines every time. The forward-thinking person inside would feel much more comfortable if there was an option to directly reference the value of out_val. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yup, this works. I'm shocked that there's no way to retrieve the output variable of a stored procedure though.

Comment: Is there a way to get direcly the value off the stored procedure OUT_VAL as ouput with `sqlplus` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `-S` (or `-Silent`) option to your sqlplus call.

```
for ... in (`sqlplus -s schema/PW@USER @"sqlcall.sql"`) do ...
```